# gcc compiler error with -D option

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, g++

I've written a makefile that compiles multiple files. when executing a line like this :

```
g++ -c -Wall -U DEBUG -U FILE -U HighPriority -U OnlyCUDA -U CUDA -U THREAD_NUM -U SIZE -U InputFileName -D FILE -D SIZE=32 -D THREAD_NUM=4 -D CUDA -D InputFileName=input/In32.txt  ../src/lib/Globals.cpp -o Globals.o
```

It generates a huge list of errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/cwchar:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/postypes.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iosfwd:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ios:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/sstream:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:47,
                 from ../src/lib/../inlcude/Globals.h:3,
                 from ../src/lib/Globals.cpp:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:48:25: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
```

but when I remove -D FILE it compiles just fine. what is this about ??

EDIT1:
the same #define FILE works fine when I use codeblocks for example. why so ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FILE` is already used in C as a file pointer object (see the `fopen(3)` manpage).

You will need to choose a different name for that constant.

The actual error is caused by the declaration of functions like `fopen()`:

```
FILE *fopen(const char *restrict filename, const char *restrict mode);
```

being turned into:

```
*fopen(const char *restrict filename, const char *restrict mode);
```

because you defined `FILE` to *nothing*.

**EDIT** Actually it's probably causing an issue in the declaration of `FILE` itself, and not the `fopen()` et al functions:

```
typedef struct __sFILE {
    ...
} FILE;
```

Where `FILE` is replaced with *nothing*.

Comment: ok but when I used codeblocks for example it worked fine with no errors. why ?? Is there a compiler option for this ??

Comment: @MohammadEwais I'm not sure why it works.  It's best avoided; tell me what `FILE` means to your program and we can work something out.

Comment: It just defines if i read input from terminal or files.. some #ifdef and #ifndef depend on it.I don't mind changing them but I wanted to know why it worked in the first place.

Comment: @MohammadEwais OK that's easily solved; change the constants to `READ_FROM_FILE` and (optionally) `READ_FROM_STDIN`.

Comment: @MohammadEwais Actually better still, support reading from both (use the symbol `-` to represent `stdin`)...

Answer (score 1):

Defining `FILE` is a very bad idea<sup>*</sup>, because it already exists as a [type in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c)!

---

<sub>* AKA "invoking undefined behaviour".</sub>